# не работает переадресация в локальной сети на vestacp

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

Добрый день! на виртуальную машину под Ubuntu 16.04 установлена VestaCP, создан домен test, при обращение по адресу http://my-local-ip/test  VestaXP возвращает 404 ошибку, phpmyadmin по адресу http://my-local-ip/phpmyadmin отвечает. Подскажите как поправить ?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в незнании основ. Чтобы обратиться к домену test на my-local-ip необходимо в hosts машины сделать запись  my-local-ip test или на dns-Сервере если он есть в сети.